# appending items to JSON file creates new list, why?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list

I have a list a JSON file and want to be able to modify it. I found the solution underneath, but what this does is create a new list, which is a copy of the existing one + the new word. So the JSON file has two lists, which is not something I want.

```
import json

new_word = input("give new word: ")
with open('vocabulary.json', "r+") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    data.append(new_word)
    json.dump(data, data_file)
```

any suggestions for adding multiple words are welcome. I tried splitting a sentence and appending the words, but that does not work (it makes a list of the words if you want to append it to a json file.

Edit: the thread [Does json.dump() append to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64687610/appending-items-to-json-file-creates-new-list-why?noredirect=1#comment114376435_64687610) did help overwriting existing data, but it still not appending. using "a" or "a+" gives an error.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does json.dump() append to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297465/does-json-dump-append-to-file)

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks! Almost :-) I can overwrite existing data, but appending new items to the list is still a problem, it creates a different list. Also, I tried adding multiple words at once by splitting the input and appending it to a temporary list and use that list as the data to put in. It works, but somehow it still puts the list in two brackets. The JSON file looks like this: [["x","y","z"]] instead of just ["x","y","z"]. Any suggestions on that?