# How do I insert data into a json list with python?

Tags: python, json, list, append

I want to add a value to a json list with python. The json file looks like this:

```json
{
    "values": [323123]
}
```

The python code looks like this:

```py
import json

#any number
id = 1234

with open("values.json", "r+") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    change = data["values"].append(id)
    json.dump(change, file)
```

and i want to make it look like this:

```json
{
    "values": [323123, 1234]
}
```

But the code results in this:

```json
{
    "values": [323123]
}null
```

Comment: There are two problems here: 1) to replace the file contents, don't use a `+` file mode; 2) `.append` modifies the value **in-place** and returns `None`. (Even if it returned the changed list, you would want to write *the entire dict* back to the file anyway, i.e. `change`). Please see the linked duplicate for the second problem; I consider the first a simple typo.

Comment: **As stated**, the question is trivial: once you have parsed the JSON data, it is *just* a collection of *perfectly ordinary* nested Python lists and dicts, which you manipulate *the same way* as if you had gotten *the same data* by *any other means*. But the question here is really a debugging question. In the future, please try to isolate the problem by [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and trying to create a [mre], focusing on one problem at a time.

Comment: For example, if writing to a file gives the wrong result, then the **first** question to ask yourself is "am I writing the correct data?" So, instead of calling `json.dump` blindly, call `json.dumps` and check the string. Oh, it only says `null`? Well, check what `data` is. Oh, it's `None`? Why did `append`ing to the list return `None`? Now you have a [searchable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) problem, and searching [is straightforward](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=why+does+appending+to+a+list+return+none+in+python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using json.dump(), you must dump the entire JSON data into the file; not just the change. Here is the code:

```
import json

#any number
id = 1234

with open("values.json", "r+") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data["filter"].append(id)
    json.dump(data, file)
```

Comment: This works!!! Is there way to remove the original list? Since {"values": [323123]} is not being overwritten, only {"values": [323123, 1234]} is being added afterwards.
Nvm i figured it out with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297465/does-json-dump-append-to-file
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Just read the file (not `r+` which is read/write), make the change, then open the file for writing and write it.  This will overwrite the original file instead of appending to it.

Note that `.append` returns `None` and modifies the list in-place, so assigning to `change` doesn't work.

Here's the correct code:

```py
import json

#any number
id = 1234

with open("values.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

data["values"].append(id)

with open("values.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(data, file)
```